# Negative Margin and Text-Align:Center

Tags: css

Some wise guy has written the following code and it works (Text centered with two lines on both sides).

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #000;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Centered</h1>
```

But I dont understand how the value `-55%` of margin-left and margin-right is calculated. If you change that to something else, it wont work.

Comment: Question is not clear, what you've tried share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll give this a shot.

Each of the pseudo-elements is 50% wide of the heading...but since there are *inside* the heading (which would normally be one line...it breaks

See:

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {}
```

```html
<h1>Text Centered</h1>
```

Well we don't want that...so we push each of them off to one side by adding the negative margins.

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -50% 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Centered</h1>
```

However, the lines are now sticking out of the box...and we don't want that. We solve this by adding `overflow:hidden` to the heading.

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Centered</h1>
```

As for why 55% specifically I can't say other than it shoud be higher than 50% to ensure the line doesn't break when the element gets narrow.

Comment: Why adding `margin: 0 -50% 0 -50%;` to the `h1` element wont work? You have to add `margin: 0 -50% 0 0;` and `margin: 0 0 0 -50%;` respectively to `h1:after` and `h1:before`.

Comment: Why `display: inline-block;`? If you change that to `block`, it wont work either.

Answer (score 0):

The -55% are moving the elements  to the right and left by 55% of the width of the `h1` element, and the 0.5 em up by half the size of the text. Since the added elements have a border bottom, this is now in the vertical middle of the `h1` and slightly outside the h1 (by 5% of the width of the h1: 50% =half plus 5%).  BTW, it *does* work with other values, here's the same changed to -60%:

```css
h1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #000;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -60% 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Centered</h1>
```